How can I set up logic to check if a Wordpress page is in spanish or english and then show different php files or fields depending which?
I have a client who has pages in English and Spanish in Wordpress. I see they have a "languages" tab where they set up the different pages but it isn't 1:1 enlgish and spanish. There's about 50 spanish pages and hundreds of english pages.
The spanish pages use the /es URL end.
What I'm trying to do is add logic to the footer and sidebar php files to check if the language is spanish, and if so, load a different set of advanced custom fields that are in spanish (instead of the normal ones that use English). Alternatively, maybe I could load different php files for each but I think the ACF swap route is easier or more straight forward. Plus, it gives more people editing access to change the text fields
Can anyone help me set this up? I've done some research but haven't found a solution. I'm assuming there's a loop to check for page language and if english use these ACF fields and if spanish use the other but not 100% how to set that up.
Thanks in advance.  I see code about determining/ echoing the current language but not about how to check for it and then conditionally display things depending on that result
The language plugin being used is "Polylang".
I'm including the sidebar.php file for reference:
 <?php

/**
 * Sidebar for 2-column templates.
 */

?>

<div class="post-sidebar content-area">

    <?php if (get_field('sidebar_call_us_description')) : ?>
        <div class="sidebar-section">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon-contact-us.png" alt="Image of a phone headset.">
            <h1 class="sidebar-title"><?php pll_e('Call Us'); ?></h1>
            <p><?php the_field('sidebar_call_us_description'); ?></p>
            <?php if (get_field('sidebar_call_other_description')): ?>
                <h1 class="sidebar-title"><?php pll_e('Call Other'); ?></h1>
                <p><?php the_field('sidebar_call_other_description'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $featured_post = get_field('sidebar_featured_post'); ?>
    <?php if ($featured_post): ?>
        <div class="sidebar-section featured">
            <h2 class="sidebar-title featured"><?php pll_e('Featured'); ?></h2>
            <div class="featured-post last">
                <h3 class="fpost-title"><?php echo get_the_title($featured_post->ID); ?></h3>
                <div class="fpost-image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($featured_post->ID, 'medium'); ?></div>
                <p class="fpost-excerpt"><?php the_field('page_header_excerpt', $featured_post->ID); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($featured_post->ID); ?>">Read more &rarr;</a>
            </div><!-- .featured-post -->
        </div><!-- .sidebar-section -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="sidebar-section">
        <h2 class="sidebar-title share">Share</h2>
  
        <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" style="display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 5px;">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/safe-horizon/"><img src="http://www.clientname.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/icon-social-linkedin.webp"></a> 
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/clientname"><img src="http://www.clientname.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/icon-social-facebook.webp"></a>
                                        <a href="https://x.com/"><img src="http://clientname.webp" style="max-width:32px;"></a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .sidebar-section -->

</div>

=== Edit ====
I tried to write code based on the suggestions and it doesn't work:
 <?php 

$code = pll_current_language() ?? pll_default_language();  

if (code == 'es') : ?>
test
<?php endif; ?>


This information seems not enough to suggest a solution. Which plugin is enabled for language localization? The plugin may already have a solution. Or, you may need to give access to the site to a developer to review it.

The plugin is "Polylang." I was hoping there was a known way in php to check for this but maybe not. I see code about determining/ echoing the current language but not about how to check for it and then conditionally display things depending on that result

Does this answer your question? How to determine the current language of a wordpress page when using polylang?

Thanks but that doesn't work. I added code to the bottom of my post of what I tried and it doesn't show. Maybe my php syntax is wrong?

If you are using Polylang, you can get the 2-letter language code with pll_current_language, so you would be able to fire logic based on that.
// Use default language as a backup
$code = pll_current_language() ?? pll_default_language(); 
if ( $code == "es" ) {
  // Do one thing
} 
elseif ($code == "en") {
  // Do a different thing
}


Thanks but that doesn't work. I added code to the bottom of my post of what I tried and it doesn't show. Maybe my php syntax is wrong?

@Mrich You have a typo in your snippet - if (code == 'es') : should be if ($code == 'es') :

thank you that fixed it looks like. Appreciate it!!
